# Can I bind a queue from a different vhost?

Tags: rabbitmq, vhosts, rabbitmq-exchange

I have an exchange with a vhost, user, etc from that exchange I bind different queues. The exchange and the queues are in the same vhost.
Now I want to create a different vhost for a different queue but I cannot bind this new queue from the previous exchange as It is in different vhost.

What is the best solution for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your requirement is typically done using the [federation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html) or [shovel](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) plugins. For your requirement a [federated exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-exchanges.html) seems the more appropriate.

If I quote your question by naming vhost:

> The exchange and the queues are in the same vhost **A**. Now I want to
>   create a different vhost **B** for a different queue but I cannot bind this
>   new queue from the previous exchange as It is in different vhost.

- You create a federated exchange on vhost **B**
- This exchange is linked to upstream exchange on vhost **A**
- The new queue on vhost **B** is bound to this federated exchange.

Comment: Thanks, This was my first option, to create a federation. Just wondering, do we have other options? As for example in my architecture we have already more than 10 federation just for this purpose..

Comment: No as far as I know, vhosts are isolated namespaces.  By curiosity, what is your use case?

Comment: I have Internal rabbit with an exchange. then I have 10 federation each one for a different client and a different queue. I was wondering if It was possible to do in another way rather than all the time to federate.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a vhost per client ? (if I understand correctly)

Comment: so every client cannot see the queue of the others. different vhost/user for each client. Then every client has access to just one exchange and one queue

Comment: I conceive permission are not suitable for your use case. Thanks for this answer

Comment: so what do you think is the best solution? Thank you for all your answers and comments

Comment: I will look first at [permissions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html), like they control access to queues, a client can have permission to access to only its queues.